# How to pass String value to another activity to play on media player Android

Tags: android

I have a string value in one activity that has file path of audio as a `TextView` and I want this to be sent to another `Activity`. which to be played on android media player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While opening the second activity from first, you can create intent and pass the string with it -

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); 
    intent.putExtra("path", "your_path_to_audio_file");
    startActivity(intent);
```

and in the second activity, in order to get the string, you do the following -

```
    String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
```

Comment: thanks its working.. and how to add this string value on create media player to play audio from file path.

Answer (score 0):

You can send any information to another activities using intents->

1. You can put String Extra -->
   myIntent.putStringExtra("MyKey","www.myurl.com");
2. You can put serializeable data class to intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass like this

```
    Intent i = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
  i.putExtra("username", "foobar"); 
  i.putExtra("in_reply_to", "george"); 
  i.putExtra("code", 400);
  // brings up the second activity
  startActivity(i);
```